# Minimum value of function $f(x)=x+\log_2(2^{x+2}-5+2^{-x+2})$ out of 5 options

Tags: logarithms

Minimum value of function $f(x)=x+\log_2(2^{x+2}-5+2^{-x+2})$ out of 5 options

A : $\log_2(1/2)$
B : $\log_2(41/16)$
C : $39/16$
D : $\log_2(4.5)$
E : $\log_2(39/16)$

I just... don't know how to approach this.

Comment: You could set $f'(x) = 0$ and solve for $x$ and see what you get, or you could fill in all the values and calculate which one gives the lowest value.. I would try the first method.

Comment: What do you mean by setting  $f′(x)=0$?

Comment: $f'(x)$ is the derivative.

Comment: Welp, I need to solve the problem with a less complex mathematical apparatus, I don't know calculus (the problem isn't predicted for students that know calc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x=\log_2(2^x)$$

$$f(x)=\log_2[2^x(2^{x+2}-5+2^{-x+2})]=\log_2[2^{2x+2}-5\cdot2^x+4]$$

Now $4\cdot2^{2x}-5\cdot2^x+4=(2^{x+1})^2-2\cdot2^{x+1}\cdot\dfrac54+\left(\dfrac54\right)^2+4-\left(\dfrac54\right)^2$ $=\left(2^{x+1}-\dfrac54\right)^2+4-\left(\dfrac54\right)^2$ $\ge4-\left(\dfrac54\right)^2$

Comment: So the correct answer is $log_2(39/16)$?

Can I ask you how you got the idea to do what you did?

Comment: @JohnDoe, Wanted to make a polynomial of $2^x$

Comment: But you ended up making one of $2^{x+1}$? Thanks! I tried something like this but didn't get the idea.

Comment: @JohnDoe, You can take out $4$ as common factor